# Qt Creator: Can not find Qt3DExtras module

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I can not include 'Qt3DExtras' module from 'Qt3D', it writes an error: `'Qt3DExtras' file not found`. Although, I installed `qt3d5-dev` and `qt3d5-dev-tools` packages and included it in the .pro file:

```
QT += core gui 3dcore 3dextras 3drender
```

Why can Qt Creator not find that file?

Comment: try with:  `sudo apt install libqt53dextras5`

Comment: It writes it is already installed.

Comment: How have you installed Qt5 and QtCreator?

Comment: I installed it from Discover, app centre.

Comment: you want to use it in qml ? or c++?

Comment: Did qt3d examples run? if yes , it's not related to your installation.

Comment: C++. What are qt3d examples? From here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-examples.html ? Not yet, but I will try out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `3dquickextras`

```
 QT += core qml quick 3dcore  3drender 3dinput 3dquick 3dlogic 3dquickextras 3dextras
```